# Old data to new structure

Tags: python, class, pickle

let's say i got some pickled data in an class structure like the following:

```
class dog:
def __init__(self, nameDog, age):
    self.nameDog = namedog
    self.age = age
    self.favoriteToys = {}
         
class toy:
    def __init__(self, nameToy):
        self.nameToy  = nameToy     
        self.color = ''
```

Now i want to load the data an use it in an new structure with an extra Attribute based on the old structure.

```
class dog:
def __init__(self, nameDog, age):
    self.nameDog = namedog
    self.age = age
    self.breed = ''
    self.favoriteToys = {}
         
class toy:
    def __init__(self, nameToy):
        self.nameToy  = nameToy     
        self.color = ''
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a class that is derived from another. That is called inheritance [Python inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

```
class Rottweiler(dog):
    def __init__(self, nameDog, age):
        super().__init__(nameDog, age)
        self.breed = ''
```

Using the `super()` function, your child class (Rottweiler) will automatically inherit the methods and properties from its parent (dog).